# VBA error 1004 modifying an excel chart

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have the following code in an MS Access 2007 database that is programmatically creating an Excel worksheet and associated chart. I get an error 1004 when trying to modify the interior color of a chart series using the .tintandshade property.

The variable 'wksIn' is an excel worksheet object passed into my Access sub. The variable 'sRange' is a string defined earlier in the subroutine.

```
...
Dim shChart as Excel.Shape
Set shChart = wksIn.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnStacked100)

Dim chChart As Excel.Chart
Set chChart = shChart.Chart

with chChart
  .SetSourceData Range(sRange)
  .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 0.2
  .SetElement (msoElementLegendBottom)

  Dim srSeries As Excel.Series
  srSeries = chChart.SeriesCollection(1)
  with srSeries
    .Interior.Color = RGB(27, 88, 124)
    .Interior.TintAndShade = 0.6              ' results in error 1004
    .SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
  End With
End With
```

I've assiduously avoided all Selects and Active______   references based on posts here. Can anyone see an obvious reason why the 1004 error might be occurring, and how to correct the problem?

An interesting side note is that the .Interior.ThemeColor property results in an 1004 error as well. Perhaps they are related?

Comment: It just means that `TintAndShade` is not a property of `Interior`. Where did you get this code from? Or maybe, that it _is_ a property of `Interior`, but `0.6` is not a valid value for this property. Go in Debug, add a watcher to `srSeries`, then search for `Interior` into the tree, and then search for `TintAndShade`.

Comment: The key here is that you're using Excel _2007_. It's getting to be more difficult to find documentation for 2007 online. Make sure that when you're searching, you include `excel 2007` in your query, and make sure the results you're looking at are for that version. I'm running 2010, and am always getting results for 2013, so I know your pain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, Interior isn't the correct property.

Replace the following lines (from your code):

```
.Interior.Color = RGB(27, 88, 124)
.Interior.TintAndShade = 0.6              ' results in error 1004
```

with the following:

```
.Format.Fill.ForeColor.Color = RGB(27, 88, 124)
.Format.Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0.6
```